# How to distribute number of users for different HTTP Requests?

Tags: performance, http, jmeter, performance-testing

My scenario is to allow 25 users to hit one HTTP Request, 75 users requesting for another request, at the same time using one or more thread groups.

```
   1. Default Request: www.abc.com
   2. 25 Users should hit www.abc.com/firstrequest
   3. 75 Users should hit www.abc.com/secondrequest
```

How can I allow such distribution of users among two or more different request at the same time using Jmeter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, You can do it with synchronizing timer but only for a request and not with multiple request.

but a tweak is possible with which you can achieve your desired load.

```
1. suppose you have 2 threadgroups having 1 request each. i.e. firstrequest and secondrequest 
2. create synchronizing timer as a child of testplan (by this it will be applicable to both threadgroups)
3. put no. of threads to group by as 100 (as you want 25 users to hit firstrequest and 75 users to hit secondrequest simulataneously, which means 100 concurrent users)
4. assign 25 thread count to first threadgroup
5. assign 75 thread count to first threadgroup 
6. Allow running threadgroups in parallel by not checking run threadgroups consecutively checkbox in testplan
```

This way you generate 100 concurrent users doing testing of 2 requests.
If you dont want 2 requests to hit simultaneously then you can add synchronizing timer to each thread group and run the test.

[image]